# TailwindCSS fixed width property not working on resolution change

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this div that's supposed to represent a button next to an input. Ideally on resolution change, the input element's width shrinks but the button stays the same height and width.

```
<div className="flex flex-row rounded-lg border border-white border-solid hover:cursor-pointer py-2 px-2 w-28">
   <AddIcon></AddIcon>
   <div className="flex font-sans text-base font-medium">Add site</div>
</div>
```

I set the `w-28` property thinking it could achieve this. However, the button changes width if I shrink the window or screen it appears on, and I'm not sure why.

This is the full component:

```
<div id="settings" className="w-3/4 h-5/6 bg-blue-300 self-center">
      <div id="settings-content" className="flex flex-col self-center mx-5">
        <div id="header" className="flex flex-col mt-5">
          <div id="title" className="font-sans font-bold text-3xl">Block Sites</div>
        </div>
        <div id="subtitle" className="font-sans text-base font-medium text-neutral-600">Visiting these sites will stop point acquisition until you reset the timer</div>
        <div id="block-site-add-list" className="flex flex-row mt-16 justify-between bg-amber-400 shrink-0">
          <div className="flex flex-row rounded-lg border border-white border-solid hover:cursor-pointer py-2 px-2 w-28">
            <AddIcon></AddIcon>
            <div className="flex font-sans text-base font-medium">Add site</div>
          </div>
          <input className="ml-5 flex-grow bg-red-500"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what the button looks like with a smaller screen, when both words should be on the same line:

[image: button screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding `whitespace-nowrap` to your label div to ensure that the text doesn't wrap to two lines. Since you have your elements (button and input) wrapped in another flex, you can add `shrink-0` to your wrapper div to keep its size.

For example:

```
<div id="block-site-add-list" className="flex flex-row ...">
  <div className="shrink-0 flex flex-row ...">
    <AddIcon></AddIcon>
    <div className="whitespace-nowrap font-sans text-base font-medium">Add site</div>
  </div>
  <input className="ml-5 grow bg-red-500"></input>
</div>
```